# Using mustache templates with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mustache

I wish to use knockout.js, but unfortunately I cannot use jquery-tmpl due to the prequisite of jquery 1.4.2, which (I won't go into it here) we cannot upgrade to.

Has anyone got any tips on getting started using Mustache templates with knockout? I've been finding it tricky to find any information regarding it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update** I've released initial version of template engine for knockout js that is using mustache as a template library. You can check it out at https://github.com/WTK/ko.mustache.js

---

Have you seen this part of documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html ? Especially take a closer look at the *Note 8* which points you to check the jqueryTmplTemplateEngine.js in the knockout source code (to spare you the effort of searching, its this one: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/templating/jquery.tmpl/jqueryTmplTemplateEngine.js).

I just took a glance at source of that file, but everything seems to be quite simple. You have to define couple of callback functions that are (I assume) called by knockout js when needed.

Those functions include:

```
function renderTemplateSource(templateSource, bindingContext, options) {}
function createJavaScriptEvaluatorBlock(script) {}
function addTemplate(templateName, templateMarkup) {}
```

Check what those functions return when using jquery.tmpl and try to mimic their behavior whilst using moustache instead.

Comment: Thanks @WTK, I did come across the docs, but must admit hadn't dug into the the source, as thought it would be mega complex. Your right it's simpler than a thought it would be. Thanks for your help, doesn't look like it's going to be something I can do within my timescale :-( but maybe something I can look at as a side project... Maybe once I've got my head around it, I'll writeup my findings... thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe I'll give it a try tomorrow. It may turn out to be simpler than it looks. Glad to be help :)